# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when importing image

Tags: python

So i am coding a game using pygame. I have a class called Player with a function called `import_assets()` where i import the names of my file and folder to import the player graphics to my game. Then at the beggining of this file i call this function and then give the value of an image to a variable called `self.status` and a value for the index called `self.index`. I then setup those informations to create an image for my player. this class goes like :

```
import pygame
from settings import *
from support import *

'class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
       def __init__(self, pos, group):
           super().__init__(group)

       self.import_assets()
       self.status = 'left_water'
       self.frame_index = 0

       # general setup
       self.image = self.animations[self.status][self.frame_index]
       self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)

       # movement attributes
       self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2()
       self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)
       self.speed = 200

   def import_assets(self):
       self.animations = {'up': [],'down': [],'left': [],'right': [],
                       'right_idle':[],'left_idle':[],'up_idle':[],'down_idle':[],
                       'right_hoe':[],'left_hoe':[],'up_hoe':[],'down_hoe':[],
                       'right_axe':[],'left_axe':[],'up_axe':[],'down_axe':[],
                       'right_water':[],'left_water':[],'up_water':[],'down_water':[]}

       for animation in self.animations.keys():
           full_path = '../graphics/character/' + animation
           self.animations[animation] = import_folder(full_path)

   def input(self):
       keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

       if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
           self.direction.y = -1
       elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
           self.direction.y = 1
       else:
           self.direction.y = 0

       if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
           self.direction.x = 1
       elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
           self.direction.x = -1
       else:
           self.direction.x = 0

   def move(self,dt):

       # normalizing a vector 
       if self.direction.magnitude() > 0:
           self.direction = self.direction.normalize()

       # horizontal movement
       self.pos.x += self.direction.x * self.speed * dt
       self.rect.centerx = self.pos.x

       # vertical movement
       self.pos.y += self.direction.y * self.speed * dt
       self.rect.centery = self.pos.y

   def update(self, dt):
       self.input()
       self.move(dt)
```

I am also using a class called `support` to help me loop trought my image folder and import the good path for the image. it goes like this :

```
from os import walk
import pygame

def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
        for image in img_files:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()
            surface_list.append(image_surf)
        return surface_list
```

My problemseems to be coming from `self.image = self.animations[self.status][self.frame_index]` that when i try to run my game im getting the error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]. Make sure that your code shows up properly, and make sure (by trying it yourself) that someone else can **copy and paste** the code **without changing anything** in order to see the **exact** problem, **directly**. There are numerous syntax errors in this code dump (wrong indentation and stray punctuation etc.) that would make it impossible to get to the `TypeError`.

Comment: It is also your responsibility to look for the problem, by carefully tracing what the code does. For example, **did you try to check** the result that you get from calling `import_folder`? Did you consider what would happen if `walk(path)` is empty? **Does it make sense** that `return surface_list` is inside the `for _, __, img_files in walk(path):` loop? Why?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. this will help me improve as i am pretty new to coding and stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with your `import_folder` return value. If `walk(path)` returns an empty iterable, then your `import_folder` function will have a return value of `None` instead of a list.

I'm not entirely sure with your foldering system, but perhaps any of the below codes could solve your issue. They have different functions depending on what you really intend to do, so you may want to try both of them.

Solution 1:

```
def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
        for image in img_files:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()
            surface_list.append(image_surf)
        return surface_list
    return [] # default return
```

Solution 2:

```
def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
        for image in img_files:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            image_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path).convert_alpha()
            surface_list.append(image_surf)
    return surface_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solution #1 worked for me ! Life saver right there

Answer (score 0):

I think your `import_assets` function is in the wrong indentation.

Fix it by adding 1 indent to the whole function code (with the `def` line) to make the function belong to class `Player`

Comment: this was actually a typo when pasting my code my bad i fexed it